# XSLT merge two XML-files if element content is the same

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to merge two XML-files in a specific way.

XML-file 1

```
<csv_data>
<row>
    <important_id>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</important_id>
    <importantstuff>very important</importantstuff>
    <alotmore>stuff</alotmore>
</row>
<row>
    <important_id>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</important_id>
    <importantstuff>very important</importantstuff>
    <alotmore>stuff</alotmore>
</row>
```

XML-file 2

```
<csv_data2>
<row1>
    <some_id>213421342134</some_id>
    <important_id>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</important_id>
    <another_id>125135345345</another_id>
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here</importantstuffhere>
    <alotmoreandmore>stuff</alotmoreandmore>
</row1>
<row2>
    <some_id>3452345</some_id>
    <important_id>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</important_id>
    <another_id>234234</another_id>
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here2</importantstuffhere>
    <alotmoreandmore>stuff2</alotmoreandmore>
</row2>
```

Merged XML-file

```
<csv_data>
<row>
    <important_id>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</important_id> (from XML-file 1)
    <importantstuff>very important</importantstuff> (from XML-file 1)
    <alotmore>stuff</alotmore> (from XML-file 1)
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here</importantstuffhere> (from XML-file 2 row1)
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here2</importantstuffhere> (from XML-file 2 row2)
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here3</importantstuffhere> (from XML-file 2 row3)
</row>
<row>
    <important_id>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</important_id> (from XML-file 1)
    <importantstuff>very important</importantstuff> (from XML-file 1)
    <alotmore>stuff</alotmore> (from XML-file 1)
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here</importantstuffhere> (from XML-file 2 row20)
    <importantstuffhere>very important stuff here2</importantstuffhere> (from XML-file 2 row21)
</row>
```

XML-file 1 has the  only 1 time, the XML-file 2 can have the same ID a couple of tousend times. Now I need the sister-elements from XML-file2 from that same ID merged with XML-File1. Is it somewaht clear what I mean?

Do I need a list of all IDs first? I really don't know where to even start here. I only know that I will need [...]apply-templates select="document('xml-file')[...].

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')//row[important_id = current()/important_id]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is not quite what I wanted, but I think I can work from here.